# Withdrawal of Notice of Allowance

Tags: patentability, patent-applications, rejected, withdrawal

After receiving an NOA and paying the fee, I was anticipating an issue notification within days. Two days after paying the fee, I instead received a Notice of Withdrawal of Allowance.

***recorks champagne***

The uploaded document, "Notice of Withdrawal from Issue Branch (PTOL-67)" shows that the application was withdrawn by the Office under 37 CFR 1.313(b), which could be for one of the following yet-unknown reasons:
(1) a mistake on the part of the Office:
(2) a violation of 37 CFR 1.56 or illegality in the application;
(3) unpatentability of one or more claims; or
(4) for interference or derivation.

Public PAIR transaction shows that there is now a non-final rejection.  It'll be a few days to find out the exact reason and then plan to act accordingly (my guess is that it is (3), due to a newly discovered prior art, but we'll see).

I understand that this is a relatively rare occurrence. My lawyer said this happens in a small % of allowed cases but I've looked through dozens of cases without finding any, and have only uncovered 2 or 3 via Google.

Any ideas how often this happens, and how I can search out more cases to review?

Answer (score 2):

It is rare. I practiced as a patent agent for about ten years and never had a NOA withdrawn. Finding other cases where this happened might not be of much help.

Until you see the office action you and your lawyer can't do anything but - from the MPEP the Notice should have indicated which of the four reasons caused this withdrawal.

> Any notice withdrawing an application from issue after payment of the
> issue fee **must specify which of the conditions set forth in 37 CFR
> 1.313(b)(1) through (4)** exists and thus warrants withdrawal of the application from issue